# Does "ring of sets" have anything to do with the "ring" in abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory

The following comes from Wikipedia.

[image]

It looks very strange to me since this "ring" seems to have nothing to do with the "ring" in abstract algebra. $(\cal R, \bigcup)$ is not an Abelian group (no inverse element if empty set is chosen as the identity), and $(\cal R, \backslash)$ is not a monoid (does not satisfy associativity). Am I right?

Then why this thing is called a ring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, it is a ring of sets under the operations

1. Symmetric difference as addition
2. Intersection as multiplication.

Under these operations, a *ring of subsets* is a ring, even an algebra over $\mathbb F_2$. To see this, consider a universal set $X$, then we have a bijection
$$A\mapsto 1_A$$
with $A$ a subset of $X$ and $1_A$ its characteristic function. Then the operations above become the normal sum and product of functions (over $\mathbb F_2$).

Comment: I made a blog post that addressed a very similar idea while proving that you can put a ring structure on any set. Great answer $+1$.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is not new though. They are known as [Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Concrete_Boolean_algebras)

Comment: Definitely not but it's still a good answer!

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you for your answer. I have a further question. What is the identity for intersection?

Comment: That'd be the set with characteristic function equal to $0$. Can you guess?

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for answering. I still don't get it. Do you mean the empty set?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you asked for intersection. That'd be the set with characteristic function $1$, i.e. the universal set $X$. It makes sense as $A\cap X=A$.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes. Thanks. That's the problem where I am puzzled. To claim $X$ is the identity, we need first show $X$ is in $\cal R$ given that the $\cal R$ is closed under symmetric difference and intersection. You can check all three definitions here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Ring_of_Sets (suppose the system of sets $\cal R$ is a subset of the power set $2^X$). I cannot see why the whole set is in the ring.

Comment: @QuangHoang Or maybe "ring of set" is not a "ring" in the algebra sense when it does not include the whole set? So the two concepts, although strongly connected, are still somewhat different?

Comment: A ring in Abstract Algebra need not a multiplicative identity (see [Wikipedia](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Ring_%28Abstract_Algebra%29) ). The axioms for Ring of Sets translate exactly to ring axioms by the identification mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @QuangHoang Ok. Right. I found there is conflict among definitions of Ring in different places. Some require the inverse element, some do not. Anyway your answer is very helpful. Thank you again.